# How am I supposed to integrate `Free Download Manager` with chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download

I have [Free Download Manager installed](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/).

When I download Free Download Manager extension [from chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-download-manager-chr/ahmpjcflkgiildlgicmcieglgoilbfdp?hl=en) It does get installed OK, but when I try to download files they are being downloaded 'normal' chrome way and usually get corrupt before finishing.

How am I supposed to integrate `Free Download Manager` with chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

You want to open installed `Free download manager` then go to

```
Options > Settings > Monitoring
```

then tick the box `Google Chrome`
[image]

it will then ask you for permission, then to close the `Chrome` (if it's open) then will automagically download and install extension.

Hope this saves you some time.